# How to get value of Checkbox using formcollection in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-views

I have a function, that collect the value of the controls of some view(.cshtml)

```
private string ExtractEmailId(FormCollection form)
{
    var value = form["CkbQuestion1"];

    return value;
}
```

I am receiving value of Checkbox as "true,false". I need the value of that control.
How I can have that?

Any Idea please.

Comment: Checkboxes are for boolean values, what value are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect you required the below code. Please replace your code with this.

```
[HttpPost]
public string ExtractEmailId(FormCollection form)
{
     var value = form["CkbQuestion1"];
     return value;
}
```

And you view will be similar to

```
@Using(Html.Beginform("ExtractEmailId"))
{
     <input type="checkbox" name="CkbQuestion1" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CkbQuestion1 must be set as value of name attribute for checkbox. It will look like this in your Html.


<input type="checkbox" name=""/>
```

it will return Empty string if you didn't define the value of value attribute. If you don't define value attribute then it will post the NULL to server.

Answer (score 0):

if you have property for that field than simply change your mark up and write

@Html.EditorFor(td => td.PropName)

and now you can access your checkbox value in controller.